# Calculating the number of functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I would like to ask:

> The number of different functions of the following type:
>   $$f: \{ 1,2,3,\ldots 2020 \}\to\{1,2,3,\ldots 2020\}$$

is $2020^{2020}$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes. The number of function from an $n$-set to an $m$-set is $m^n$.

Comment: Yes, and the number of bijective functions is $2020!$

Comment: Thank you very much.